# What does "estar devendo na praça" mean?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

### English

Today I heard someone saying "*Estou devendo na praça*" (something like "I owe in the square") in an ironic tone, after receiving a *spam* email with the subject of "clear your name" (in relation to debts).

I don't hear this expression very often, but it seems to me that "*estar devendo na praça*" is commonly used to mean "to be in debt".

I imagine this is only a partially correct meaning, as the "square" part is lost. So my question is: what is the real meaning of this expression? Is "square" a synonym for "court" (*I owe money in court*)? And another one: is this an expression used only in Brazil?

---

### Português

Hoje ouvi uma pessoa dizer "estou devendo na praça" em tom de ironia, após ter recebido um e-mail de *spam* com o assunto de "limpe o seu nome" (em relação a dívidas).

Não escuto essa expressão com frequência, mas me parece que "estar devendo na praça" é comumente utilizado com o significado de "estar devendo dinheiro".

Imagino que este seja um significado apenas parcialmente correto, pois perde-se a parte da "praça". Então minha dúvida é: qual o real significado dessa expressão? Seria a "praça" um sinônimo para "tribunal" (*estou devendo no tribunal*)? E outra: esta é uma expressão utilizada apenas no Brasil?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esse *praça* vem com certeza da seguinte aceção do dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002):

> **praça** […] **5** comunidade comercial e financeira de uma cidade <*ter crédito na praça*>

O [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/pra%C3%A7a) apresenta definição igual e exemplo parecido. O [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pra%C3%A7a/) diz o mesmo em outras palavras:

> **3** Conjunto de casas comerciais e bancárias de uma cidade: “*Campos, depois do casamento, principiou a prosperar de um modo assombroso; dentro de três anos era, o que vimos, rico, muito acreditado e seguro na praça*” [Aluísio de Azevedo, 1884]

Um exemplo de [J. Adolpho Ribeiro da Silva (Rio de Janeiro, 1874)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9OdGAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA236&dq=%22devendo%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVuJ3J-KnzAhWgBmMBHUrRAfgQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22devendo%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&f=false) dá um ar mais concreto à coisa. Um ex-estudante, antes de regressar a casa, vende tudo menos a roupa que levava no corpo, para “limpar contas com um resto de credores”, pois “um bacharel não deve retirar-se **devendo na praça**”. Já se falava em *dever na praça* em 1829 [(Annaes do Parlamento Brazileiro)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=am5XAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA22&dq=%22devia%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijn8WC_anzAhWEzoUKHeRlDZMQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22devia%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&f=false), e de *crédito na praça* em 1720 [(António de Sousa Macedo, Lisboa)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bTZcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA566&dq=%22credito%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMrbjc_7DzAhVFcBQKHSttBosQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22credito%20na%20pra%C3%A7a%22&f=false).

Este *dever na praça* parece ser exclusivamente brasileiro. Eu, aqui em Portugal, não conhecia. Procurei no Google restringido a Portugal, Angola, Moçambique e Cabo Verde, e não encontrei nada (procurei também *dever, devia, devem*; tudo isso encontrei no Brasil, mas nada nos outros países). Eu pelo contexto — dívida e necessidade de limpar o nome — compreendi mais ou menos do que se tratava. Até porque se ouve falar de *praça financeira*, especialmente a propósito de centros importantes como Londres ou Nova Iorque. Mas se ouvisse sem mais contexto, aqui na rua em Setúbal,  alguém dizer *estou a dever na praça*, pensariam que tinham ficado a dever a um vendedor do [mercado aqui de Setúbal, a mais das vezes referido por *a praça*](https://www.google.com/search?q=mercado%20do%20livramento%20set%C3%BAbal&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwiz3OiNjKrzAhWeSfEDHYrfCAwQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1#imgrc=GaDF3qPexb67HM) — um mercado retalhista sobretudo de produtos frescos, principalmente frutas e legumes, peixe e carne.

Comment: A definição do Houaiss, "comunidade", é muito melhor que a do Michaelis, na minha opinião. Não acredito que deixei de checar esse dicionário! :-) +1

Comment: +1 pela definição. No Brasil existem ainda estabelecimentos com placas dizendo "só aceitamos cheque da praça" (embora esteja caindo em desuso), em grande parte por causa da diferença de prazo de compensação dos cheques, e para devolução de cheques devolvidos que foram depositados fora da praça

Comment: @Juliana, gostei imenso de saber dessa placas! Devem ser mesmo muito antigas: pagamento com cheque já deve ser raro...

Answer (score 7):

### English

The expression is familiar to me and I always understood "*praça*" to mean<sup>1</sup> here either

1. "around", "out there", "in town"; or
2. "market", in an economic sense — perhaps referring to the economy in the past and in small towns having often revolved around the regular street market and local businesses surrounding its central square.

So "Estou devendo na praça." would simply be a colloquialism for "I'm in debt (out there)." or "I have debts (in town)."

### Português

A expressão me é familiar e sempre entendi que "praça" significava<sup>2</sup>

1. "por aí", "na cidade"; ou
2. "no mercado", num sentido econômico — talvez em referência à praça ser, no passado e em pequenas cidades, o centro econômico do lugar, devido à feira e às lojinhas circundando a praça.

Então "Estou devendo na praça." seria apenas uma maneira coloquial de dizer "Tenho dívidas / Estou devendo (por aí / na cidade)."

<sup>1: See Jacinto's [answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8935/2764) for a reference confirming the meaning: "a city's commercial and financial community".</sup>
 <sup>2: A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8935/2764) do Jacinto tem uma referência confirmando o significado "comunidade comercial e financeira de uma cidade".</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Eu sou do Recife, Brasil. Aqui na minha região, "estar devendo" é generalizado: Se você fez algo de errado e as pessoas estão desconfiadas de você em função disso, então você "está devendo na praça". Onde "praça" significa: "Algum lugar, instituição ou pessoas relevantes à questão, e que usualmente é entendido pelo contexto.

### Exemplos:

- Se você deve dinheiro, então você está "devendo na praça".

> *Aqui, "praça" significa: "Lugar onde você está devendo dinheiro".*

- Se você foi visto fazendo um pequeno furto e as pessoas estão desconfiadas de você por causa disso, então você está "devendo na praça".

> *Aqui, "praça" significa: "As imediações do lugar onde você foi visto furtando algo e/ou as pessoas que viram você".*

- Se você fez alguma coisa errada e teme retaliação, então você está "devendo na praça".

> *Aqui, "praça" significa: "Lugar de onde você teme que virá a retaliação".*

- Eu lembro de uma vez que eu fiz cócegas na minha namorada, aí quando ela se aproximou de mim, eu temia que ela me fizesse cócegas também, ela me viu ficando defensivo e disse: "Tá com medo porque tá devendo na praça, né?".

> *Aqui, "praça" significa: "Minha namorada".*

Comment: Que legal, todas as vezes que ouvi o "está devendo na praça" era com relação ao dinheiro. Não sabia que outras regiões usavam para outros significados também.

Comment: @RafaelTavares  É metafórico.  "Ah, ele sabe que está devendo na praça" pode ser interpretado literalmente mas pode ser uma metáfora.